# Background color diagonal split responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, translate-animation

I'm using Bootstrap.

I need to achieve this result :
[image]

For that I started doing this :

```
<body>
    <div id="diagonal-bg"></div>
</body>

#diagonal-bg{
  position: absolute;
  left: -800px;
  width: 200%;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(118deg, #fff 35%, #8aa8ec 35%);
}
```

It works almost because as soon as I resize my window here is what I get :
[image]

How can I have distances A and B to be always the same across different size of screen/window, to make it responsive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue :

```
<div class="background">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #23d6c5;
}
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #2f3441 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

---

```css
body{
  background-color: white;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #2f3441;
}
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #2f3441 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution below interested for 
Background color diagonal split responsive

```css
.shape {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.top {
    height:0;
    border-width:150px 400px 0px 0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#d71f55  transparent #d71f55  transparent;
}
.bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#d71f55;
}

/* Support transparent border colors in IE6. */
* html .top {
    filter:chroma(color=#123456);
    border-top-color:#123456;
    border-left-color:#123456;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shube the result is good but A & B are not fixed according to the visitor screen. If I resize my window it change :(